# Create a generic class

Tags: generics, parameters, constructor, getter-setter

Write a generic class Pair which has two type parameters—F and S—each representing the type of the first and second element of the pair, respectively. Add set and get methods for the first and second elements of the pair and be sure to demonstrate your setters/getters actually work. (Hint: The class header should be public class Pair<F, S> and the best way to demonstrate your setters is to call them from your constructor(s).)

Write a separate PairTest class to test class Pair. Create 2 Pair types and test your get and set methods on the following pair types:
 Pair<Integer, String> p1 takes Integer and String types as a pair
 Pair<String, Integer> p2 takes String and Integer

PairTest should output enough information to the terminal to show that your generic class Pair is able to set() and get() different types.

I just need help writing this code.